# web3.eth.getBalance returns always zero

Tags: synchronization, balances

I have an ether account (whose details I prefer not to disclose here).  I can confirm in `etherchain.org` that it has the correct amount of funds.  I can also check that the funds were transferred in block `3639426`

I am running geth on my linux desktop with the plain command

`geth`

i.e. no "-fast" or nothing enabled.  At the moment:

```
 currentBlock: 3953293,
 highestBlock: 4161833,
 knownStates: 62693,
 pulledStates: 58536,
 startingBlock: 3914231
```

So, at this stage I should be able to check the balance of my account also from geth console using

```
web3.eth.getBalance("..")
```

.. right?

However, I get zero all the time.

Starting to feel cold sweat: I think I've been screwed.. just don't know how!  Why I'm getting zero balance?

A Bonus question: what's the essence of "startingBlock" ?

** EDIT **

Phew.. using **any** account gives me a zero.  So, is it so that the blockchain must be downloaded completely before checking account balances works .. ?  I guess so.

** EDIT EDIT **

OK, it's finally synchronized & everything works as expected. .. I am using

`Geth/v1.7.0-unstable-6ca59d98/linux-amd64/go1.8.3`

I wonder if "-fast" is now the default..?

Answer (score 2):

When doing a sync with `geth --fast`, you will not get any state information until the sync is fully complete. A slow sync will give you incremental state along the way, but take significantly longer.