# Why the balance that I see in the Ropsten isn't reflected in Truffle console?

Tags: truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ropsten, truffle-migration

This is my account #1: http://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6bc701e7c3b642fc12a3a6f7d1144b8200a26401

and I sent some ETH to account #2: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xb1862a4949553c993267054dfc10a8e76d83819b

Here's how I ran `geth`:

```
➜  voting_truffle geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

But why I'm still seeing `0` balance through the Truffle console?

```
truffle(development)> web3.personal.unlockAccount('0xb1862a4949553c993267054dfc10a8e76d83819b', 'somepass', 15000)
true
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getBalance('0xb1862a4949553c993267054dfc10a8e76d83819b').toString()
'0'
truffle(development)>
```

Here's few info about my env:

```
truffle(development)> version
Truffle v4.0.1 (core: 4.0.1)
Solidity v0.4.18 (solc-js)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: A thought, is your geth node synced? Incorrect balance is often caused by not being synced.

Comment: @comodoro how do you check and make sure that my `geth node` is synced? I'm now seeing a lot of `WARN [11-29|16:17:17] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=573b6b30d1c97e7c err="retrieved ancestor is invalid"`

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11233/how-to-check-my-sync-status-on-geth-1-5-5-raspberry-pi-3 might still be valid, i.e. enter geth console and enter `eth.syncing`. If there are errors, you might have to restart it or start from scratch.

Comment: @comodoro still doesn't seem to work with me, see this: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/c27def5f6407a5e8c34073d97d988a77

Comment: Etherscan.io (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x60a9e63750adfafc77bd0ba692a20e4dbe330c24) shows the transaction at 2179599, so you are just below it or already have it by now. Current block now is 2182087.

Comment: I'm already above that block now, and I still don't see it: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/74bbb320b686f0b99b03749adae3ca97

Comment: So I searched a bit and according to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/24413/1771) `geth --fast` must be fully synced before showing _any_ balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I don't see the Ropsten number in my `geth console` is because I don't have the block FULLY SYNCED.

Need to make sure that the block is fully synced before you execute `web3.eth.getBalance('0xb1862a4949553c993267054dfc10a8e76d83819b')`

```
> eth.syncing
false
> web3.personal.unlockAccount('0x60a9e63750adfafc77bd0ba692a20e4dbe330c24', '123456', 0)
true
> web3.eth.getBalance('0x60a9e63750adfafc77bd0ba692a20e4dbe330c24')
2000000000000000000
>
```