# unable to deploy contract on ropston testnet

Tags: testnets, ropsten, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I am trying to deploy contract on ropston testnet. I have created an account through truffle console and got three test ethers from https://faucet.bitfwd.xyz/. I have confirmed that my account has three ethers from this https://ropsten.etherscan.io/. But when I check balance from truffle console it always says zero. Although my node is synced.

`web3.eth.getBalance('0x06ac473de96986b20b37f13ca311d07c0875e49b')
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }`

here is screenshot of  https://ropsten.etherscan.io/ which clearly shows it has three ethers.

[image]

When I do truffle migrate I get following error.
[image]

Please help my finding where mistakes occur. Thanks in advance :)

**Edit**

Here is my truffle.js

`module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*',
      gas: 470000
    }
  }`

Comment: Are you certain that your local ethereum node is connected to Ropsten?  And have you checked your node's logs to see if there's anything informative there?   You may want to consider testing with infura:  http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `truffle migrate` tries to migrate to ropsten ( with an e) ? 
It says "using network development" in your screenshot. You should have ropsten declared as a network in your truffle.js.

So: Please check wether you a) are checking your balance on ropsten via truffle console, and b) wether you are actually trying to migrate to ropsten.

Edit: I added Ropsten like this into my truffle.js :

```
ropsten:  {
     network_id: 3,
     host: "localhost",
     port:  8545,
     gas:   450000
}
```

Then migrate via `truffle migrate --network ropsten`

Regarding the balance, please check 
[Why the balance that I see in the Ropsten isn't reflected in Truffle console?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31881/why-the-balance-that-i-see-in-the-ropsten-isnt-reflected-in-truffle-console)
and make sure you really are in sync.

Comment: i have added truffle.js in edit. please have a look at question again

Comment: my rpc localhost server is running on portno. 8545

Answer (score 0):

Ropsten is deprecated by 5 Oct. 2022 and i don't think there is any validators left to manage your transactions.

Try using Goerli testnet instead.